# MySQL use certain columns, based on other columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, xml, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(articles.id) AS count 
FROM articles, xml_documents, streams 
WHERE articles.xml_document_id = xml_documents.id 
AND xml_documents.stream_id = streams.id
AND articles.published_at BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-04-01'
AND streams.brand_id = 7
```

Which just uses the default equajoin by specifying three tables in csv format in the FROM clause.. What I need to do is group this by a value found within articles.source (raw xml).. so it could turn into this:

```
SELECT COUNT(articles.id) AS count, ExtractValue(articles.source, "/article/media_type") AS media_type
FROM articles, xml_documents, streams 
WHERE articles.xml_document_id = xml_documents.id 
AND xml_documents.stream_id = streams.id
AND articles.published_at BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-04-01'
AND streams.brand_id = 7
GROUP BY media_type
```

which works fine, the problem is, I'm using rails, and using STI for the xml_documents table. The **articles.source** that is provided to the *ExtractValue* method will be of a couple different formats.. So what I need to be able to do is use "/article/media_type" IF xml_documents.type = 'source one' and use "/article/source" if xml_documents.type = 'source two'

This is just because the two document types format their XML differently, but I don't want to have to run multiple queries to retrieve this information..

It would be nice if one could use a ternary operator, but i don't think this is possible..

**EDIT**
At this Point I am looking at making a temp table, or simply using UNION to place multiple result sets together..

Comment: MySQL supports dynamic SQL via Prepared Statements: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html

Comment: Not sure how that would help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>What about something like this:</strike>

```
SELECT COUNT(articles.id) AS count,
       ExtractValue(articles.source,
           CASE xml_documents.type WHEN 'source one' then '/article/media_type'
                                   WHEN 'source two' then '/article/source'
                                   ELSE 'error'
           END),
FROM ...
```

**EDIT**
Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(articles.id) AS count,
       CASE xml_documents.type WHEN 'source one' THEN ExtractValue(articles.source, '/article/media_type')
                               WHEN 'source two' THEN ExtractValue(articles.source, '/article/source')
                               ELSE NULL
       END as media_type,
...
```

Comment: I was pumped when I saw this, seems like it should work, but MySQL throws "Only constant XPATH queries are supported", which to me, means that only strings are accepted here, not a case statement..? Ideas?

Comment: That's disappointing. The only alternative that occurs to me is to write a stored procedure, but according to the docs that will only work with mysql 5.1.20 or newer.

Comment: Bummer, our server is running the latest Ubuntu package which is packed with MySQL Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.75, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64). Well I guess I will have to try and just union the multiple sets..

Comment: Could this be done using a left join of some sort? Joining the same table multiple times with different criteria...

Comment: perfect! Thanks for staying with me

Comment: Great! It was a bit of a face-palm moment, not sure why I didn't think of it sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I would support the previous poster:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(articles.id) AS count,
    (CASE xml_documents.type
        WHEN 'source one' THEN ExtractValue(articles.source, '/article/media_type')
        WHEN 'source two' then ExtractValue(articles.source, '/article/source')
        ELSE NULL
    END) as media_type,
FROM ...
```

Comment: @Rabbott: I just had posted the query before he updated his answer. the idea was the same anyway.